# Can't run XCode templates

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm new to iPhone development and have run in to a problem.

This is what I do;

Create a new project (any type, unchecking Use storyboards).
Running it.

This is the error I get;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', 
reason: '[<UIApplication 0x6a35470> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

I haven't added any code at all yet, so this suprises me a bit.
Should I not be able to run an 'empty' app?

When I use storyboards I can run the project, add all the objects and code I want and run it just fine.

It just feels like I'm missing something really simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the comments in the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're missing something really simple.
Select your project on top left, select your target and check where it says:
Main Storyboard:
Main Interface:
You have to have a window to start up with....

[image]

Comment: This is ofcourse my bad for not writing it in the question but I actually have set the Main Innterface to the xib file that was created when I created the project.

Comment: Maybe you should try reinstalling it. My projects work just fine as soon as I start xcode I always run them to make sure it's working. If they aren't then there's something strange. Or if you installed one of those weird API's that could be an issue too.

Comment: Haven't installed any third party stuff.
I'll try a fresh install, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ok cool. let me know if it works. If it doesn't I guess the next step would be to ask the apple geniuses lol. I'm curious to know what this is.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. I didn't help to reinstall, I even got a brand new Macbook (not because of this ofc) and tried the same thing, same problem.

Comment: Found the problem. I assumed (incorrectly) that you had to set the Main Interface like in the screenshot above. However when I left that blank it works. I guess that when you load the xib in code and have the Main Interface set it tried to load it twice.